# gcloud compute copy-files succeeds but no files appear

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am copying data from my local machine to a compute engine instance:

`gcloud compute copy-files /Users/me/project/data.csv instance-name:~/project`

The command runs and completes:

```
data.csv 100%   74KB  73.9KB/s   00:00
```

However, I cannot find it anywhere on my compute engine instance. It is not visible in the `~/project` folder. Is it failing silently or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you sure you're logging in into your GCE instance with the same username that was in use on your local machine when you copied the file? Your file is most likely on your instance but under a different /home/<USER>

Comment: That was the problem. I needed to add user@instance to get it working. Thanks! Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: Ok, done – with an expanded explanation ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

Most likely, you're looking into the wrong `$HOME`. Make sure you're looking
in the home directory of the same user you're copying from (it will be
created on the remote host if it didn't previously exist).

### Not-so-short answer

If you don't specify any remote user when invoking `copy-files`, then `gcloud`
will try to figure out which user to login with. You can see this in action if
you take a look into `gcloud` source code:

```py
# $CLOUD_SDK_ROOT/lib/surface/compute/copy_files.py

# [...]

user_host, file_path = arg.split(':', 1)
user_host_parts = user_host.split('@', 1)
if len(user_host_parts) == 1:
    user = ssh_utils.GetDefaultSshUsername(warn_on_account_user=True)
    instance = user_host_parts[0]
else:
    user, instance = user_host_parts

# [...]
```

In your case, since you didn't specify any user, `GetDefaultSshUsername()`
will be called, and its mission is to find a valid SSH username to
use. To do so, it will pick the first option that qualifies in the following
order:

1. Use current `$USER` if it's valid under GCE-specific constraints—namely,
   ASCII characters containing no whitespaces.
2. Otherwise, extract the username from the `gcloud` account currently logged
   in (you can check which one it is by running `gcloud auth list`)

Once again, source code tells us the ultimate truth:

```py
# $CLOUD_SDK_ROOT/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/ssh_utils.py

def GetDefaultSshUsername(warn_on_account_user=False):
    # [...]
    user = getpass.getuser()
    if not _IsValidSshUsername(user):
        full_account = properties.VALUES.core.account.Get(required=True)
        account_user = gaia_utils.MapGaiaEmailToDefaultAccountName(full_account)
        if warn_on_account_user:
            log.warn('Invalid characters in local username [{0}]. '
                     'Using username corresponding to active account: [{1}]'.format(user, account_user))
        user = account_user
    return user
```

So, now that we know how the process of picking a remote username roughly
works, my educated guess is that you copied your `data.csv` file using a
different user than the one that was later on checking on the remote instance
if the file was there, since by default they'll land on their
respective –and different– `$HOME` directory.