# Moving a directory from local-machine to an instance in GCP

Tags: bash, file, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to move a folder from my local machine to the remote server in an instance of GCP:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse myDirectory instance-1:~/Folder
```

It looks like it is uploaded (because I see the files uploading), but when I checked the folder at the remote server there is nothing. What I am doing wrong?

I have two projects and I set up gcloud with the suitable project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is inspired by: [gcloud compute copy-files succeeds but no files appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688880/gcloud-compute-copy-files-succeeds-but-no-files-appear)

I needed to write username@instance, thus this works:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse myDirectory username@instance-1:~/Folder
```